# Batch class to update all contacts whose accountid's not equal to null

Tags: apex, batch, schedulebatch

[image: Batch Apex error]I have written a batch class to update all contacts(lastname) whose accounts not equal to null.

Am not getting any error,but its not updating when executed from anonymous block. Please find the below code and do needful.

**Code :**

```
global class batchContactUpdate implements Database.Batchable<sObject>
{
/*
       // String query = 'select id, Name, (select  LastName from Contacts) from Account';
       global batchContactUpdate(Id AccountId){
       this.AccountId= AccountId;
   // this.acc= acc;
} */
       set<id> AccIds = new set<id>();
       global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

        String query = ' select id from Account';
        AccIds.add(query);
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact> scope) {
scope = \[select id,firstname, lastname from contact where Accountid = : AccIds \];
         for(Contact con : scope)
         {
         if(con.accountid != null)
             con.LastName = con.LastName + 'sfdc';            
         }
         update scope;
    }   

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Does not show much effort to resolve as states No error but clearly in the log there is an error. Batch is not even possible to execute as scope is account and loop iterates over contact. Code will not even compile

Comment: Hi @Eric : I have made the above changes,but still the contacts are not getting updated. Please suggest me the right approach to fix this.

Comment: Please do not modify your question to make it an entirely new question. You question was answered - Question was about the error - If an answer solved that mark it as accepted if you wish. If you have a follow up question please create a new one. Why? Because updating the question like that removes all context for the answers provided and makes it tough for others with similar issue to find answers. Feel free to add additional detail to the end of the question if not fully answered

Comment: Review debug logs to ensure that the query actually returns records....If there are no contacts without an AccountId then nothing will be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting and error and the error is pretty specific:

> Invalid Id: 'Select Id From Account'

If you read the error you understand that you are attempting to add your query string to the `AccIds.add(query);` which obviously is a bad idea.

Also, your batch is attempting to query all accounts in the start method so you are not even creating a batch that works on the contact.

Once you figure that out, how will you now which account to assign to a given contact that does not have an Account Id.

I am going to vote to close the questions as well as it really does not show any effort on your part to even attempt to diagnose or review your code.